# Не загружается axaml Designer. Ошибка: Avalonia.Designer.HostApp/Program.cs:line 47

Tags: c#, avalonia

Вот функция, где я думаю есть ошибка:

```
public override async void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
        {
#if !DEBUG
            if (!_isUniqueInstance)
            {
                var uri = new Uri($"avares://BK_Launcher/Assets/BK-studio.png");
                IAssetLoader? asset = Container.GetService<IAssetLoader>();
                IBitmap image = new Bitmap(asset?.Open(uri));

                IMsBoxWindow<ButtonResult> messageBoxStandardWindow = MessageBox.Avalonia.MessageBoxManager
                    .GetMessageBoxStandardWindow(
                     new MessageBoxStandardParams()
                     {
                         MinWidth = 300,
                         ButtonDefinitions = ButtonEnum.Ok,
                         ContentTitle = "Ошибка",
                         ContentMessage = "Программа уже открыта!",
                         WindowIcon = new WindowIcon(image),
                         Icon = Icon.Error,
                     }
                    );
                await messageBoxStandardWindow.Show();
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
#endif

            DbContextOptions options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlite(_connectionString).Options;
            using (ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(options))
            {
                RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(dbContext.Database);
            }
            var initializationHandler = Container.GetRequiredService<InitializationHandler>();


            var userStore = Container.GetRequiredService<UserStore>();

            //Avalonia.Threading.Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => 
            //{
            await initializationHandler.Initialize();

               
            //});


            INavigationService projectNavigationService =
                Container.GetRequiredService<NavigationService<ProjectNavigationStore, ProjectListingViewModel>>();
            projectNavigationService.Navigate();

            INavigationService serviceNavigationService =
                Container.GetRequiredService<NavigationService<ServiceNavigationStore, ServiceListingViewModel>>();
            serviceNavigationService.Navigate();

            INavigationService keyProtectionNavigationService =
                Container.GetRequiredService<NavigationService<KeyProtectionNavigationStore, KeyProtectionViewModel>>();
            keyProtectionNavigationService.Navigate();


            User? user = await userStore.LoadCached();

            INavigationService firstPersonalAccountService =
                user != null && await userStore.Login(user) ?
                Container.GetRequiredService<NavigationService<PersonalAccountNavigationStore, PersonalAccountViewModel>>() :
                Container.GetRequiredService<NavigationService<PersonalAccountNavigationStore, LoginPersonalAccountViewModel>>();

            //INavigationService? firstPersonalAccountService = default;

            //Avalonia.Threading.Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() =>
            //{
            //Task.Run(() =>
            //{

            //    User? user = userStore.LoadCached().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            //    firstPersonalAccountService =
            //       user != null && userStore.Login(user).GetAwaiter().GetResult() ?
            //       Container.GetRequiredService<NavigationService<PersonalAccountNavigationStore, PersonalAccountViewModel>>() :
            //       Container.GetRequiredService<NavigationService<PersonalAccountNavigationStore, LoginPersonalAccountViewModel>>();
            //}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            //});



            firstPersonalAccountService?.Navigate();


            if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
            {
                desktop.MainWindow = Container.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
                desktop.MainWindow.Show();
            }

            base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
        }
```

Под комментариями мои попытки исправить функцию.

Вывод:

````
12:35:05.335 [Information]  Starting previewer process for '"F:\Repositories\BK-Launcher\BK_Launcher\bin\Debug\net6.0\BK_Launcher.dll"'
12:35:05.338 [Information] 21832 Started previewer process for '"F:\Repositories\BK-Launcher\BK_Launcher\bin\Debug\net6.0\BK_Launcher.dll"'. Waiting for connection to be initialized.
12:35:05.737 [Information] 21832 Connection initialized
12:35:06.851 [Error] 21832 <= "Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'table \"Projects\" already exists'."
12:35:06.855 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)"
12:35:06.861 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()"
12:35:06.862 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()"
12:35:06.862 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()"
12:35:06.862 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)"
12:35:06.862 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()"
12:35:06.863 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()"
12:35:06.863 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)"
12:35:06.864 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)"
12:35:06.864 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)"
12:35:06.864 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)"
12:35:06.865 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)"
12:35:06.866 [Error] 21832 <= "   at BK_Launcher.App.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted() in F:\Repositories\BK-Launcher\BK_Launcher\App.axaml.cs:line 203"
12:35:06.867 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Avalonia.Controls.AppBuilderBase`1.Setup() in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/AppBuilderBase.cs:line 312"
12:35:06.867 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Avalonia.Controls.AppBuilderBase`1.SetupWithoutStarting() in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/AppBuilderBase.cs:line 167"
12:35:06.867 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Avalonia.DesignerSupport.Remote.RemoteDesignerEntryPoint.AppInitializer`1.ConfigureApp(IAvaloniaRemoteTransportConnection transport, CommandLineArgs args, Object obj) in /_/src/Avalonia.DesignerSupport/Remote/RemoteDesignerEntryPoint.cs:line 154"
12:35:06.868 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Avalonia.DesignerSupport.Remote.RemoteDesignerEntryPoint.Main(String[] cmdline) in /_/src/Avalonia.DesignerSupport/Remote/RemoteDesignerEntryPoint.cs:line 179"
12:35:06.868 [Error] 21832 <= "   at Avalonia.Designer.HostApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /_/src/tools/Avalonia.Designer.HostApp/Program.cs:line 47"
12:35:07.589 [Information]  Process exited
12:35:07.591 [Information]  Stopping previewer process
12:35:07.589 [Error]  Connection error
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Avalonia.Remote.Protocol.BsonStreamTransportConnection.<ReadExact>d__15.MoveNext() in /_/src/Avalonia.Remote.Protocol/BsonStreamTransport.cs:line 56
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Avalonia.Remote.Protocol.BsonStreamTransportConnection.<Reader>d__16.MoveNext() in /_/src/Avalonia.Remote.Protocol/BsonStreamTransport.cs:line 72

```
Подскажите, как исправить?
````

Comment: Дополните вопрос !

Comment: у вас почему-то запускается миграция на базе в которой уже есть таблицы

Comment: Добавил  перед этим код: if(Database.EnsureCreated()). Ничего не изменилось. Все ошибки возникают только при открытии .axaml.cs файлов. При этом дизайнер интерфейсов не открыватся